# Embed YouTube Video on VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce

new to visualforce. Having a play around.

Anyone know why this wont embed on VF page? When i preview i just get a blank page

```
<apex:page >
<apex:iframe width="854" height="510" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SGPvYQ1o2x4" frameborder="0"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: aren't you missing the http: in the src tag?

Comment: I guess this is a case where [protocol relative URLs](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/04/18/protocol-relative-urls/) don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [protocol relative](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/04/18/protocol-relative-urls/) source URL does not work. Try:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:iframe width="854" height="510" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SGPvYQ1o2x4" frameborder="0"/>
</apex:page>
```

*-Answer edited to incorporate Keith C's comment*